# Reading n characters from keyboard with AutoIt (like a keylogger)

Tags: keyboard, barcode-scanner, autoit, keylogger

I would like to handle numeric barcodes with a small script in the language AutoIt under Windows.

How can I intercept the next 9 characters from the keyboard with AutoIt?

My barcode reader emulates a keyboard. To distinguish real keyboard input from barcodes I have programmed the barcode reader to add a prefix (`scrollock`) and a suffix (`@`) to each barcode.

AutoIt recognizes the prefix and starts the function `getbarcode()` but I did not find a command to read from keyboard input. Instead I found a no-keylogger-policy. So I tried the `InputBox`, a widget with a single input field and an OK button. It was too slow for me. The keyboard input activates the current windows and the `InputBox` is pushed into the background.

```
#include <Misc.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Global $HotKeyActive = True
HotKeySet("{ScrollLock}", "getbarcode")

While 1
  Sleep(1000)
WEnd

Func getbarcode()
  If $HotKeyActive = True Then
    $HotKeyActive = False
    $InputString = InputBox("Artikelnummer", "Artikelnummer")
    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Debug", $InputString, 10)

    $HotKeyActive = True
  EndIf  
EndFunc
```

I tried it a second time by defining 10 more functions that are executed when the keys 0 to 9 are pressed, using `HotKeySet`. Each function appends its number to a global string. The global string is reset by the prefix-function and used by the suffix-function. It works, but the sequence of the characters is wrong. There seems to be a timing problem.

For the third attempt I let the barcode reader emulate a serial device and try to read the com-port from AutoIt.

Comment: Have you tried setting global HotKeys for all of your Numbers always saving the last 9 ones and only process them when when they come in a small amount of time else pass them forward to Windows using `Send(...)`?

Comment: @Samoth, I have set global HotKeys for all numbers, appending the number to a global string. The sequence of numbers was shuffled; due to timing problems I guess. I can recognize the start of a barcode by a special character (scrollock). The end of the barcode can be recognized by another character ("@" in my case) or the number of characters or a timeout.

Answer (score 1):

This can help you out. It basically sets HotKeys for each Number (and Numpad-Number) and calls a Function to save these as well as Timestamps when they were pressed. When you now enter 9 Digits within one Second the Output displays the discovered Barcode. Else the Number-Keystrokes are just sent forth to Windows as usual.

```
#include <Array.au3>
#include <Date.au3>

Global $numbers[][] = [["0", "Zero"], ["1", "One"], ["2", "Two"], ["3", "Three"], ["4", "Four"], ["5", "Five"], ["6", "Six"], ["7", "Seven"], ["8", "Eight"], ["9", "Nine"]]

Global $flush[9] = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
Global $last = $flush
Global $time[9]

Global $findTimeInSeconds = 1

For $i = 0 To UBound($numbers) - 1
    HotKeySet($numbers[$i][0], $numbers[$i][1])
    HotKeySet("{Numpad" & $numbers[$i][0] & "}", $numbers[$i][1])
Next

While True
    Sleep(1000)
WEnd


Func check()
    If StringRegExp($last[8], "[0-9]") And _DateDiff("s", $time[8], _NowCalc()) < $findTimeInSeconds Then
        ConsoleWrite(_ArrayToString($last, "") & " (Barcode found)" & @CR)
        $last = $flush
    Else
        HotKeySet($last[0])
        Send($last[0])
        HotKeySet($last[0], $numbers[$last[0]][1])
    EndIf
EndFunc

Func Zero()
    _ArrayPush($last, "0", 1)
    _ArrayPush($time, _NowCalc(), 1)
    check()
EndFunc

Func One()
    _ArrayPush($last, "1", 1)
    _ArrayPush($time, _NowCalc(), 1)
    check()
EndFunc

Func Two()
    _ArrayPush($last, "2", 1)
    _ArrayPush($time, _NowCalc(), 1)
    check()
EndFunc

Func Three()
    _ArrayPush($last, "3", 1)
    _ArrayPush($time, _NowCalc(), 1)
    check()
EndFunc

Func Four()
    _ArrayPush($last, "4", 1)
    _ArrayPush($time, _NowCalc(), 1)
    check()
EndFunc

Func Five()
    _ArrayPush($last, "5", 1)
    _ArrayPush($time, _NowCalc(), 1)
    check()
EndFunc

Func Six()
    _ArrayPush($last, "6", 1)
    _ArrayPush($time, _NowCalc(), 1)
    check()
EndFunc

Func Seven()
    _ArrayPush($last, "7", 1)
    _ArrayPush($time, _NowCalc(), 1)
    check()
EndFunc

Func Eight()
    _ArrayPush($last, "8", 1)
    _ArrayPush($time, _NowCalc(), 1)
    check()
EndFunc

Func Nine()
    _ArrayPush($last, "9", 1)
    _ArrayPush($time, _NowCalc(), 1)
    check()
EndFunc
```

It has a little downside: The numbers before a barcode is recognized will be printed out... so one should check all Numbers typed so far and oppress them while still in a small amount of time. That's the tended readers challenge.